# Slack App won't post in a designated channel, only in channel it is invoked in

Tags: slack, slack-api, slack-commands

The Json getting returned is simple

```
{
    "channel": "<channel id>",
    "Text": "Hello"
}
```

yet it just posts "Hello" in the current channel I am in, rather than the channel I specified. I want "Hello" to be posted in the designated channel.

Comment: Ensure you have the right channel ID. If you are using the bot token ensure that you have invited the bot to the channel.

Comment: try chat.postMessage and specify the channelId you want to post